# Threejs isolated reflection shader using cubeCamera not working

Tags: reflection, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

**jsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/t2pv9ku0/8/ demonstrates my problem.

I'm trying to re-create the reflection effect in ThreeJS using a `RawShaderMaterial`. There are [several](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2.html) [examples](http://demo.romanliutikov.com/three/8/) [of](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html) this effect, which is pretty standard.

A [`cubeCamera`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/CubeCamera) is created and passed into the shader to provide the `samplerCube`:

```
material.uniforms.reflectionSampler.value = cubeCamera.renderTarget;
```

A reflection vector is calculated in the **vertex** shader:

```
varying vec3 vReflect;
...
vec3 inverseTransformDirection( in vec3 normal, in mat4 matrix ) {
    return normalize( ( vec4( normal, 0.0 ) * matrix ).xyz );
}
...
vec3 worldNormal = transformDirection( objectNormal, modelMatrix );
vec3 cameraToVertex = normalize( worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition );
vReflect = reflect( cameraToVertex, worldNormal );
```

It's used in the **fragment** shader to read from the `cubeCamera`'s render:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4( vNormal.y ) + textureCube( reflectionSampler, vReflect );
```

However, as you can see in the jsFiddle, **the effect does not appear to be working correctly.** It appears to be reading the sample position incorrectly from the `samplerCube`. I've tried fiddling with everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cube camera is not part of the scene, so you must call

```
cubeCamera.updateMatrixWorld();
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2pv9ku0/9/

Alternatively, you can add the cubeCamera to the scene.

three.js r.71

**Edit by Andy** Here is a fiddle with reflection code https://jsfiddle.net/t2pv9ku0/11/ that mimics three's reflection

Comment: Thank you, I'm guessing my bug report helped realize that :)